# My app list does not show the app created previously on LinkedIN developer

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi, omniauth-linkedin

I created the app details for providing "Sign in with LinkedIn" for my website users. The error on login is

> The application is disabled

Now on the LinkedIn developer portal, the app list is empty.

How do I  pull out the app details on the linkedin developer page to make the "login with linkedIn" work for my users ?

I can still see the linkedin page for my app but it is not associated with my app because the app does not appear in My app list. How do I provide admin access to my linkedin page ?

Comment: Sounds like the app was deleted or had its ownership transferred to somebody else.

Comment: How to regain ownership ? Cannot create new app because new client id and key would be generated which will need to be updated on the website .

Comment: Either ask the current owner to transfer it to you or talk to Linkedin's developer support (assuming they even have such a thing). Why is updating the client id/key a problem? You said it's your website.